# Which tv-commercial was it with every 32th a different musician?

Tags: identify-this-song, soundtrack

I'm looking for this tv-commercial which aired a few years ago. It had music composed for so many musicians, every 32th or 16th orso had a musician. It was shot in 1 go and sounded brilliant, I thought it was for Coke orso. But although I've searched and googled, I can't seem to find it anywhere.

Does anyone recognize this ad?

Comment: It would be helpful to know where you life... Not all TV-Spots are shown in all countrys... (i guess you are from US, but it could also be more than 200 other countries...)

Answer (score 1):

If you're asking about a single ad with many interpreters then BBC used to do stuff like this.

They did one in 1997 featuring Lou Reeds' [Perfect Day](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WJpQJWpVJds) to promote their diverse music coverage. They did another one last year (2014), for the launch of BBC Music. The latter is [God Only Knows](http://www.bbc.co.uk/programmes/p0286057) by The Beach Boys.

Comment: Lou Reed's 'Perfect Day' cover was a charity single, if I remember correctly. With Bono, Bowie, Shane MacGowan and a few others.

Comment: @n00dles it was released as a charity later.  The original had the message: "Whatever your musical taste, it is catered for by BBC Radio and Television. This is only possible thanks to the unique way the BBC is paid for by you. BBC. You make it what it is."

Comment: Yeah, You're right.

Answer (score 0):

Was it the Discovery Channel's *[The World Is Awesome](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5wOKQmO-ftk)* campaign (the "Boomdiada" song).  It isn't a perfect match, but it had a different vocalist every line.

There's also the Playing For Change "[Songs Around the World](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Us-TVg40ExM)" project, which created versions of songs by having different musicians play them from all around the world; or [Thru You](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tprMEs-zfQA&list=PL2C189BC49E25D16A) which created original music as a mashup of different videos found on YouTube. Neither of them, however, were commercials.